# What's the difference between ruby-1.9.3-p194 and ruby-1.9.3-p194@global gemsets?

Tags: ruby, rvm, gemset

I am currently running the following on OSX 10.6.8 and am trying to understand gemsets and gems.

Ruby 1.9.3-p194

Rails 3.2.8

RVM 1.15.6

When I look in .rvm/gems/ I see several gemset directories. Inside each one there is a gems directory. Now, whats the relationship between the non-'@' gemset and the @global gemset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://rvm.io/gemsets/global/):

> #### Interpreter global gemsets
>
> RVM provides (>= 0.1.8) a `@global` gemset per ruby interpreter.
>
> Gems you install to the `@global` gemset for a given ruby are available
>   to all other gemsets you create in association with that ruby.
>
> This is a good way to allow all of your projects to share the same
>   installed gem for a specific ruby interpreter installation.

To expand on this, the gemset without the `@global` is the default gemset for that Ruby version. It is essentially a gemset with no name. The `@global` gemset, however, is special for the reasons outlined in the docs above.

Comment: Hey Andrew, thanks for the help. I'll do some more reading there.

Comment: Followup question - if I change gemsets with $ rvm gemset use default and do a $ gem list I see different gems listed. Why does this happen?

Comment: @rjd Different compared to what?

Comment: Oh I just found the explanation:


NOTE: A little bit about where the default and global gemsets differ. If you don't use a gemset at all, you get the gems in the 'default' set. If you use a specific gemset (say @testing), it will inherit gems from that ruby's @global. The 'global' gemset is to allow you to share gems to all your gemsets. The word 'default' quite literally says it all, eg. the gemset used without selecting one for a specific installed ruby.


https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/